# Is it possible to be an expert in a skill at level 2?

Tags: feat-qualifications, pathfinder-2e-playtest

In the first public draft of the Pathfinder 2e playtest (Aug. 2018), there are several second level feats that require expert in various skills. One example is Magical Crafting. It seems as if it is not possible to have an expert rank in a skill until level 3 when you get your first skill increase. Is it possible for any character to choose one of these skill feats at level 2?

Comment: Should this question be updated to be about Pathfinder 2e print?

Comment: @Ifusaso no because the question *is about* the playtest material, not the official released material. Changing the question might invalidate the current accepted answer (whether the answer is the same for the playtest and the official rules, I don't know) and wouldn't preserve the original meaning of the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes, it's possible

There are ways to become *Expert* in a skill as early as 2nd level, such as the **Gnome** racial feat **Obsessive**:

> Pick a category of the Lore skill. You are trained in that skill. At 2nd level you become an expert

**Rogues** also gain a skill increase at 2nd level, and another skill increase *every level*, instead of every 2 levels like the other classes (starting at 3rd):

> At 2nd level and every level thereafter, you gain a skill increase. You can use this increase to either become trained in one skill you’re untrained in, or become an expert in one skill in which you’re already trained.

So, it seems like all those Acrobatics and Athletics themed feats available at 2nd level are just at the right level for rogues to get them. Magical Crafting, as weird as it sounds, is also possible for a 2nd level rogue. While other classes would have to wait to take it at 3rd level or later.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you take certain dedications, you get to go expert in something if you're already trained.  As of today, they're in Lost Omens: World Guide and Advanced Players Guide.

A few examples:

- Pathfinder Agent dedication-go expert in anything you're already trained in
- Aldori Duelist-Acrobatics or Athletics & Dueling Lore
- Lastwall Sentry-Athletics & Undead Lore
- Lion Blade-Deception or Stealth & Espionage Lore
- Acrobat-Acrobatics
- Marshal-Diplomacy or Intimidation

Comment: This seems to be an answer about current Pathfinder 2e content; but the question was about the Playtest. I'm not sure if this is an invalid answer or if the question should be updated to be about the actual print 2e.