# Is it possible to be expert in a skill at level 1?

Tags: skills, pathfinder-2e-playtest

Related to: [Is it possible to be an expert in a skill at level 2?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129380/is-it-possible-to-be-an-expert-in-a-skill-at-level-2)

In hero labs online when you get skills through feats or backgrounds (lore as an example) you can add another skill level as usual. In that case, they are having 2 levels though and called expert there.

What I'm interested in now is:
Is that really possible and doable to be expert at level 1? (or is that in hero labs a bug so to say)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's not possible to train on a skill twice at 1st level

I checked for all references of *proficiency*, *trained* and *expert* in the playtest book, and there is absolutely no reference of a general rule that when you obtain a *Trained* proficiency twice in a skill, it increases to *Expert*. The only reference of such thing is on the **Skill Increase** (page 42) class ability that all classes get:

> This section specifies the levels at which your character
>   can increase her proficiency rank in a skill. At 3rd level
>   and every 2 levels thereafter, most classes grant a skill
>   increase, though rogues gain them earlier and more often.
>   Your character can use this skill increase to either become
>   trained in one skill in which she’s untrained or **become an
>   expert in one skill in which she’s already trained**.

This, of course, could be *unintended*, as there are several ways to start with a character *Trained* on a skill from two sources, especially since the skill proficiency gained from your class is free. You can pick whatever skill you want when choosing your class, as the *Signature* skills are suggestions (page 42), though some higher level abilities will affect those more specifically, and you are generally limited to *Expert* proficiency in non-signature skills (page 144).

However, since picking those skills is a *choice*, it's not weird if you say that you are picking the skills you *want to be trained at*, so picking a skill twice wouldn't make any sense. Regardless, my searches at the playtest forums found no similar questions. Thought a few users mention that you cannot gain higher than Trained in a skill at creation([here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2vbke?Skill-and-General-Character-Progression#2), [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2vazk?1st-Level-Skill-Boosts#2), and [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2vbnd?Can-one-be-expert-in-a-skill-at-character#1)), which makes me think that this may have been mentioned or hinted by the developers on another media (paizocon or podcasts), or (most likely) they simply accepted what is written in the book as literal (*"You are trained in X"*) and didn't consider it a possibility.

So, until further clarification, I would say that *Hero Lab* is wrong on this subject.

Comment: after your post I double checked on the forums and they brought up a good point here: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2vbnd?Can-one-be-expert-in-a-skill-at-character#1  (I overread that so far seemingly the exact woirding that its always get trained,...)

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that while gaining the same skill from multiple sources (Background and Class) tells you to "instead become trained in a skill of your choice", the *free* skills you pick from can be spent to raise a trained skill up to expert.

My reasoning behind this is that there are 2nd level feats that require a player to have an Expert skill proficiency. Since your first skill boost isn't until 3rd level the only way to make use of one of those feats, without waiting to level up, is if it can be increased before then and the only skills that are not pre-defined are those "free" skills.

Comment: This would be a much stronger answer with quotations from the relevant sources.

Comment: Rogues get a skill increase at level 2. They can take those level 2 skill feats that require Expert proficiency.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: It's also possible that it was intended as future-proofing for special abilities that allow for Expert skills earlier than they are currently